# Regex positive lookahead not matching as expected

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have to use a regular expression to match several strings and capture parts of the string.

Example strings could look like:

---

- robert ***eric*** palmer sent for the boat
- robert ***eric william*** palmer sent for the boat

---

The goal is to lazy match and capture the ***middle name*** of robert palmer up to the point where the surname (**palmer**) appears in the string **AND** ensure the rest of the string matches the static text (robert ___ palmer sent for the boat).

I have used a positive lookahead to find the middle name and stop matching if **palmer** is found:

`/robert (.+?)(?=\spalmer) palmer/`

which correctly matches;

`robert eric palmer`

`robert eric william palmer`

and correctly doesn't match;

`robert eric william palmer palmer`

---

**The problem:**

when I add the rest of the static text to the regex;

`/robert (.+?)(?=\spalmer) palmer sent for the boat/`

it incorrectly matches;

```
robert eric william palmer palmer sent for the boat
robert eric palmer palmer sent for the boat
```

How can I lazy match up to **palmer** for the middle name and still assert the rest of the static text matches?

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Maybe all you need is `robert (.+?) palmer sent for the boat`? The `(?=\spalmer)` is redundant in `robert (.+?)(?=\spalmer) palmer sent for the boat`

Comment: i need it to stop matching if palmer exists in between “robert” and “palmer” though, so “robert eric palmer” is fine but “robert eric palmer palmer” shouldn’t match.

Comment: Then, the third example - `robert eric palmer palmer sent for the boat` - should be no match and you want `robert ((?:(?!palmer).)+?) palmer sent for the boat`

Comment: this seems to work as required but i’m not sure how? would you mind breaking it down?

Comment: To be clear, your requirement is "match all words after robert and before [the first palmer], if that is followed by this string." Your current regex is "match all words after robert and before the first [palmer that is followed by this string]". It's close, but not exactly the same. Wiktor gave a good regex answer for this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please don't edit the question just to fit your answer better. This should be done by the OP. I rolled back to the original question and think you're on the wrong track here. I think OP wants to match `eric` in `robert eric palmer palmer sent for the boat`. Only Norix can clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
robert ((?:(?!palmer).)+?) palmer sent for the boat
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hV61oP/1).

**Details**

- `robert`  - a literal substring
- `((?:(?!palmer).)+?)` - a capturing group #1 with a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) that matches any char (`.`), 1 or more occurrences but as few as possible, that does not start a `palmer` char sequence
- `palmer sent for the boat` - a literal substring.

To unroll the pattern for better performance use

```
robert ([^p]*(?:p(?!almer)[^p]*)*) palmer sent for the boat
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hV61oP/2).

Comment: Nice answer +1. Also in this case the lazy +? does not do anything useful, I believe it should be the same as the greedy one.

Comment: @justhalf I'd rather stick to a lazy quantifier here, as the text between `robert` and `palmer` should not be longer than the rest of the string. Maybe it makes sense to add `robert` there, `(?:(?!palmer|robert).)+?`

Comment: @justhalf thank you for you answer above but I think the answer from Wiktor is exactly what I needed here. Thanks both for taking the time to look at this and Wiktor, thank you for breaking down the answer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I mean, due to the negative lookahead, the regex with or without the lazy quantifier match the same set of string. Because the capture group can only match exactly before the first palmer in either case. I like the idea of unrolling it too!

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the lookahead in your sample is unneeded. If you want to lazily match the part until `palmer` with [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `palmer` and a specified substring after it, add it to the pattern.

```
robert (.+?) palmer(?:.* palmer)? sent for the boat
```

The optional *greedy* `(?:.* palmer)?` will **consume the gap** between *lazy* part and `sent for the boat`.

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XIX4Sf/1)   [`(?:`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions)opens a *non capturing group*)

---

For just consecutive `palmer` after, an idea to use [`robert (.+?) (?:palmer )+sent for the boat`](https://regex101.com/r/XIX4Sf/4)

Answer (score 0):

What about using a greedy match instead? For example:

```
robert (.+) palmer
```

Otherwise it potentially would leave at the first occurrence of palmer instead of the last. Example [here](https://regex101.com/r/T5f4z8/1).

[image]